# How to view an openGL renders generated from PC's c++ code on an Android Device connected via WiFi?

Tags: android, c++, video, opengl-es, stream

I'm working on an Augmented Reality (AR) demo in which high quality openGL renders (in C++) will be generated from a PC and then streamed to an Android display device (running minimum Android 2.2).  What is the easiest way to achieve this in real-time (30 FPS on Android Device) ?

I've looked into existing Anrdroid applications, and have not found anything to be suitable so far.  The best available were remote desktop applications (such as TeamViewer) however the frame rates were far too low and unreliable.

Possible solution A:
1) Encode openGL window as H.264 Video (natively supported by Android)
2) Stream the H.264 Video via RTSP using a server
3) View the content from an Android Browser (android and pc connected via WiFi)

Possible solution B:
1) Encode openGL window as IP Camera in c++ (is this possible?)
2) Use an IPCamViewer on Android device to view (again connected via WiFi)

I'm not entirely sure if either or both of these approaches are viable and would like some reassurance before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

What is the resolution of the image (is it equal to the current screen resolution, larger or smaller)? It is possible and efficient to transport a H.264 stream, but it also depends on the machine used to do the encoding. Hardware encoders or GPU-accelerated encoders are your best bet.

**Remember** - *if you choose to go with encoding, you will have latency due to buffering (on the encode and the decode side). It will be a constant time offset so if that's not a problem you should be ok.*

The total system delay as proposed by [this](http://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/pub-inf_4978.pdf) paper is composed of
[image: Compression, transmission and display latency]

Note that none of these delays can be fully measured directly in frame-time. Some of these depend on the frame data and/or the encoder/processing performed. But as a rough estimate with fast GPU-encoding and hardware decoding I'd say a lag of around 5-20 frames. You'll have to measure the final latency per-scenario. I did this by sending frames containing text (ticks) and once the frames were steady, comparing them side-by-side. In fact, I even allowed the user to enter "test mode" at anytime to compensate for network traffic peak times or have him change the "quality" settings to tweak this delay.

Comment: I would render the openGL window to match the screen resolution of the display.  I have access to machines with powerful graphics cards that could be utilized for GPU-accleration.Roughly how much time offset should be expected?